# Options for input data file types?

Tags: .net, xml, json, editor

I am working on a project that collects and analyzes moderately complex engineering data.  Many people will be creating the data, but only a few actually performing analysis.  A goal is to have this input data be in "documents" that are authored by the experts and machine readable, so there is no translation between the authors and the analysis.  (This has been a source of error with current methods.)  I have been struggling with how best to achieve this.

A prototype used Microsoft InfoPath 2007 forms as a means of data entry, where the program read the resulting XML.  This sort-of worked, but the forms couldn't really handle the complexity very well, and were very difficult to revise when the requirements changed.  Additionally, most users are still stuck with Office 2003.

I am exploring the idea of structured plain-text input files that are written manually.  Most users aren't comfortable with XML and would refuse to write using it.  Inventing a custom language and parser seems like a nightmare.  JSON seems ... reasonable, but not really meant for human use.

Are there any other options for input that I should consider?

Comment: "prototype used Microsoft InfoPath 2007 forms". Can you elaborate on this possibly?

Comment: We had created several forms in InfoPath, with the required/optional fields, with structured repeating groups etc. to capture the data needed.  Some automation was provided within the forms to do some complex validation or lookups.  As the entered data is stored in an XML format, it was easily consumed as input by the program.  However, we found that the complex forms were really difficult to develop.  Forms with lots of data were unbearably slow.  Due to limitations (or perhaps our lack of skills), we were unable to create form layouts that made good sense to the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A goal is to have this input data be
>   in "documents" that are authored by
>   the experts and machine readable

It sounds very much like you need an application level input to support your "expert" users. This should include all manner of data input validation and verification.

The result of the data input will then be a usable XML format.

The application itself can be quite simple but still facilitate the data entry process.

Comment: After looking at my options, I am planning to use this approach.  Data validation is an important part of this task.  I have more control over how this works in a custom application than trying to fit some other UI/framework.

Also, I am (finally) brushing up on WPF, and *really* liking it so far.  I think many of my UI wants will be easy, whereas they would have been difficult with WinForms...

Comment: Another benefit:  I can use the same classes within the data entry application as my main application, and simply serialize them.  This should make the data transfer between the two a snap!

Comment: I would also always opt for more control when I can. Using existing solutions is fine for most things but when requirements get complex or change often over time it becomes a limitation instead. As regards WPF, if you're coming from a classical WinForms background then I'd recommend looking at this video which describes the transition to WPF/MVVM http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv

Answer (score 1):

Excel.  No really.  Your users are used to using it and it's everywhere (even on the web now if you're using SP 2010).  It can be customized ad nauseum.  You're going to have to jump through hoops to get the data out, but I know of at least one major project at an insurance group that uses Excel with about 1000 templates for generating life insurance/key man insurance quotes.

One thing (I forgot to add): don't get the excel data out using COM if you can avoid it.  It's messy.  Try and use some of the built in Excel services stuff to do it.  I know that Microsoft has made a big push for this sort of thing recently, unfortunately I've not have enough experience with it to help further.

Comment: I up-voted this because because it is a very viable solution in general.  It gets used this way around here, including a recent project I was on (although I did not make the decision to use it nor do the interfacing code).  Maybe it's my lack of imagination, but I don't think it will work for the level of complexity that I need - basically, very dynamic forms...